# Do screen_view events get logged automatically in iOS extensions?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

We're switching over to using Firebase for analytics from the old GAI SDK.

I have it set up and working in our app and app extension.  Each uses it's own plist from Firebase to match the bundleID.  What I'm finding is that the automatic logging of screen views (the `screen_view` event) in the extension are not logged at all.

I can see other events from our extension stream as shown here:

[image: events]

So does automatic logging of `screen_view` not work in extensions or am I missing something?  I didn't see anything in the docs indicating that it wouldn't work.

Comment: As it turns out firebase doesn't support extensions at this time according to their support.